# trying to add two seperate functions, each one have a button targeting one component react JS

Tags: reactjs, state, styled-components

im trying to give the jsx element a background, and i have two functions, function one gives the background gray and the second function gives it green.. so far i managed to add the two functions to the jsx elemnt through `onClick` however, when clicking both buttons it only run the green function

```js
const [onTwo, SetTwo] = React.useState(false);

function toggleTwo() {
  SetTwo((prevstate) => !prevstate);
}

const [green, setGreen] = React.useState(false);

const color = {
  backgroundColor: green ? "#94D7A2" : "transparent",
};

function checkAnswers() {
  setGreen(true);
}

return (
  <h2
    className="answer-two"
    style={{ ...stylesTwo, ...color }}
    onClick={() => {
      toggleTwo();
      checkAnswers();
    }}
  >
    {props.answertwo}{" "}
  </h2>
);
```

Comment: You never use `onTwo`

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you edit the same property `backgroundColor`? The latter will be in the final object. `{ ...{ backgroundColor: '#D6DBF5' } , ...{ backgroundColor: '#D6DBF5' } } -> { backgroundColor: '#D6DBF5' }`

Comment: then how do i change its background with two buttons ?

Comment: Could you explain what's the expected behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

you set the background color, but in your case, I guess you need to toggle this  function `toggleTwo` on every click and change that function to

```
function toggleTwo(){
  SetTwo(!onTwo)
}
```

then that state will interchange between true and false every time u click

here is my working example I change one of backgroundColor to color to confirm its working,
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mclean-vgiukl?file=/src/App.js